# Generate a Random Number that Stays for more than one PHP Process?

Tags: php, random, numbers

I have done some research on this and discovered the **rand(), srand(), and mt_srand()** yet they don't work too well for me.

I want PHP to generate a random ID (number) and then have it stay that way no matter how many times you refresh the page.
I suppose this could be done with incrementing operators or session variables? Cookies perhaps?

Comment: yep; sessions/cookies

Comment: random for one or all visitors and for how lang?

Comment: forever and all visitors

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it with sessions for a random number between 42 and 1337:

```
session_start();
$random_nb = $_SESSION['random_nb'] ?: ($_SESSION['random_nb'] = mt_rand(42, 1337));

echo $random_nb;
```